# how can I get p-value if there is score value of genomic interval given?

Tags: r, p-value

I am wondering about this. if the expression for score value of genomic interval as: gr$score = log10(gr$p-value); then p-value will be : gr$p-value = 10^ -10/ gr$score. for me, the expression for getting p-value in this way is not elegant. Is that correct and formal expression for converting p-value in R?

```
expression 1: gr$score = -10*log10(gr$pvalue)
             OR
             gr$score = -1* log10(gr$pvalue)

expression 2: gr$pvalue = 10^ -10/ gr$score
```

How can I normalize pvalue given expression 1? Thanks all

Comment: when you put `gr$p-value` you actually mean `gr[, "p-value"]`, not `gr$p - value`, right ? (if `gr$score = log10(gr$pvalue)`, then `gr$pvalue = 10^gr$score`)

Comment: I edited original post. in bed files, there is 1 column metadata that indicate score value of GRanges. so I need to use pvalue instead of score. gr$score= log10(pvalue). Do you think my conversion is okay?

Comment: generally pvalue betweem 0 ~ 1. I think your answer is not correct.

Comment: I don't see the link between the fact that a pvalue is in ]0;1] and the fact that f(x)=10^x is the reciprocal function of f(x)=log10(x) (in appropriate domains). (you can check yourself with for example pvalue=0.05)

Comment: I just confirmed the expression again from other sites. expression will be : gr$score = -10* log10(pvalue). so my conversion for pvalue is correct ,right ?

Comment: sorry if I misunderstood you but actually it is not at all what you wrote, you wrote `gr$score = log10(gr$pvalue)` and in this case, it would make gr$score=10^gr$pvalue. but if `gr$score = -10* log10(pvalue)` then `gr$pvalue=10^(-gr$score/10)` so not what you put actually

Comment: @CathG: thank you. your correction is helpful !!

Comment: Voting to close as either off-topic or no longer reproducible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

let's generate this reproducible data first:

```
gr <- GRanges(
  seqnames=Rle(c("chr1", "chr2", "chr3", "chr4"), c(5, 6, 4, 3)),
  ranges=IRanges(seq(1, by=9, len=18), seq(6, by=9, len=18)),
  rangeName=letters[seq(1:18)], score=sample(1:25, 18, replace = FALSE))
```

then pvalue:

```
pvalueBase <- c(1,10,100)
p.value <- 10^(score(gr)/(- pvalueBase))
```